# Popular search terms with special characters give useless search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search, special-characters

Using the new jobs search on SO careers, if you search for C# in the "what" box, it performs a search for C, missing off the # symbol.

[Example](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=c%23)

Comment: It fails for "asp.net" as well (strips the period, ending up with "aspnet"). http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=asp.net And C++: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs?searchTerm=c++

Comment: I was really hoping using c%23 would work, but it translates that to a pound sign, *and then discards it anyway*. Humorously, if you search for c%23, the "what" box says "c#", but if you enter c# in the url the "what" box says "c". Both are still searching just c.

Comment: Given all these failed (very popular) searches, I have no idea how the current UI passed through their testing phase.

Comment: @jon, didn't you get the strunk & white already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi, indeed we were stripping out too many special characters. You should find this resolved now. Thanks for the heads-up!